# Oracle function, how to pass parameters to cursor and use it

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is one of oracle functions. There is a cursor called `c_adv_course_credit` which receives 2 parameters. These 2 parameters are using the where statement:

```
WHERE
    -- year
    cc.year = p_year AND
    -- rela_pk
    cc.sequence_number = p_sequence_number AND
    cc.closed_ind = 'N';
```

When I run it in oracle sql developer:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
variable res varchar2(200);
EXECUTE :res := advp_test_cursor(2018, 92919);
select :res from dual;
```

The result text is always `"not working"`

Here is the full function (not working):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function SISD_OWNER.advp_test_cursor (
        p_sequence_number IN NUMBER, -- rela_pk
  p_year IN NUMBER  -- year
)
RETURN VARCHAR2     
IS
v_return_var VARCHAR2(300) := 'not working';

CURSOR c_adv_course_credit (
  p_sequence_number IN NUMBER,
  p_year IN NUMBER
)
IS
  SELECT 
    cc.EXTERNAL_COURSE_CD
  FROM
    adv_course_credit cc
  WHERE
    cc.year = p_year AND
    -- rela_pk
    cc.sequence_number = p_sequence_number AND
    cc.closed_ind = 'N';
BEGIN
  FOR v_at_rec IN c_adv_course_credit(p_sequence_number, p_year) LOOP
    v_return_var := v_at_rec.EXTERNAL_COURSE_CD;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('?output = ' || v_return_var);
    EXIT;
  END LOOP;    
  RETURN v_return_var;
END;
```

If I change the cursor to use hard-coded numbers the function works and returns actual result.

```
WHERE
        -- year
        cc.year = 2018 AND
        -- rela_pk
        cc.sequence_number = 92919 AND
        cc.closed_ind = 'N';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is defined as (ignoring the data types):

```
advp_test_cursor(p_sequence_number, p_year)
```

but you're calling it as

```
advp_test_cursor(2018, 92919);
```

which has the arguments the wrong way round. You either need to flip them:

```
advp_test_cursor(92919, 2018);
```

or use [named parameter notation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#GUID-A5DA8CF5-1BCC-4ABE-9B68-DB593FF1D2CC):

```
advp_test_cursor(p_year=>2018, p_sequence_number=>92919)
```

or indeed combine both:

```
advp_test_cursor(p_sequence_number=>92919, p_year=>2018)
```

Comment: Avoiding this sort of confusion is the top reason for using named parameter notation.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use cursors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function SISD_OWNER.advp_test_cursor (
  p_sequence_number IN adv_course_credit.sequence_number%TYPE,
  p_year            IN adv_course_credit.year%TYPE
) RETURN adv_course_credit.EXTERNAL_COURSE_CD%TYPE
IS
  v_return_var adv_course_credit.EXTERNAL_COURSE_CD%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT EXTERNAL_COURSE_CD
  INTO   v_return_var
  FROM   adv_course_credit
  WHERE  year            = p_year
  AND    sequence_number = p_sequence_number
  AND    closed_ind      = 'N';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('?output = ' || v_return_var);

  RETURN v_return_var;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN 'Not working';
END;
```